# Accessing PDF files on SD card on Android Device

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-intent, android-sdcard

I am currently developing an app for android which would allow a User to Upload a PDF file from their SD card to the servers. I've looking at a tutorial to upload an Image to a server to understand the technical aspects of uploading a file.

```
Intent pickImageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(pickImageIntent, REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE);
```

I was looking at this and wondering how I would edit this code so the user could access the SD card and select a PDF file rather that the media store gallery?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create an `Intent` like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
// Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select PDF"), REQUEST_PICK_PDF);
```

This will allow the user to select any type of file so you'll have to check the extension in `onActivityResult(...)` and proceed accordingly.

Comment: If you change the string in intent.setType to "application/pdf" then it should only show the PDFs that are in the folder being browsed on the SD card.

Comment: I tried that before posting the answer but it didn't work.

Comment: Ah ok. I have had some luck with Android and minetypes, yet we always had to resort to looking at the file extension as well.

Comment: @BrandonHaugen we can never be too cautious. :D